# How to get displayed sizes of mouse cursor in program on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cursor, size, mouse

I need to know the displayed size of mouse cursor in my C++ Windows 10 program.

On Windows 10, I make the pointer larger to display, say 5x than the original. (In Cursor & Pointer settings).

[image]

Then, in my C++/MFC program, I tried these:

```cpp
int nXCursor = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR);
int nYCursor = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR);
```

or

```cpp
int nXIcon = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
```

or

```cpp
HICON ico = (HICON)GetCursor();
SIZE res = { 0 };
if (ico)
{
   ICONINFO info = { 0 };
   if (::GetIconInfo(ico, &info) != 0)
   {
      BITMAP bmpinfo = { 0 };
      if (::GetObject(info.hbmMask, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpinfo) != 0)
      {
         res.cx = bmpinfo.bmWidth;
         res.cy = bmpinfo.bmHeight;
      }

      ::DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
      ::DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);
   }
}
```

They all come back with 32, which is original.

Does anybody know how to get the displayed, enlarged cursor size?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is stored in registry. There is a DWORD value `CursorSize` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Accessibility`. In your case it should be 5.